# Folium Choropleth doesn't change colors on tiles

Tags: python, gis, geospatial, folium, choropleth

```
DF = pd.DataFrame({'REGION_ID':list(range(0,88)), 'share': list(map(lambda x: x* 5.3, list(range(0,88))))})

m = folium.Map(location=[63.391522, 96.328125], zoom_start=3)

rel_ = folium.Choropleth(
       geo_data = './admin_level_4.geojson', 
       name = Имя',
       data = DF,
       columns=['REGION_ID', 'share'], 
       key_on='id',
       bins = 10,
       fill_color='BuGn',
       nan_fill_color='darkblue',
       nan_fill_opacity=0.5,
       fill_opacity=0.7,
       line_opacity=0.2,
       legend_name= 'Легенда',
       highlight = True,
       show = False
)

rel_.add_to(m)
```

In the tutorials they are mentioned that REGION_ID should correspond the same REGION_ID from geojson, but I cant find any ...

```
gpd.read_file('./admin_level_4.geojson').columns.values
array(['flag', 'ref', 'name', 'note', 'is_in', 'koatuu', 'place',
   'ref:en', 'ref:ru', 'ref:uk', 'source', 'int_ref', 'name:ab',
   'name:af', 'name:ar', 'name:av', 'name:az', 'name:ba', 'name:be',
   'name:bg', 'name:bs', 'name:ca', 'name:ce', 'name:cs', 'name:cu',
   'name:cv', 'name:cy', 'name:da', 'name:de', 'name:el', 'name:en',
   'name:eo', 'name:es', 'name:et', 'name:eu', 'name:fa', 'name:fi',
   'name:fr', 'name:fy', 'name:ga', 'name:he', 'name:hi', 'name:hr',
   'name:hu', 'name:hy', 'name:id', 'name:is', 'name:it', 'name:ja',
   'name:ka', 'name:kk', 'name:ko', 'name:ku', 'name:kv', 'name:ky',
   'name:la', 'name:lb', 'name:lt', 'name:lv', 'name:mk', 'name:mn',
   'name:mr', 'name:ms', 'name:nb', 'name:nl', 'name:nn', 'name:no',
   'name:oc', 'name:os', 'name:pl', 'name:pt', 'name:ro', 'name:ru',
   'name:se', 'name:sh', 'name:sk', 'name:sl', 'name:sq', 'name:sr',
   'name:su', 'name:sv', 'name:sw', 'name:ta', 'name:tg', 'name:tl',
   'name:tr', 'name:tt', 'name:ug', 'name:uk', 'name:ur', 'name:uz',
   'name:vi', 'name:yi', 'name:zh', 'alt_name', 'website', 'boundary',
   'int_name', 'name:aba', 'name:ace', 'name:ast', 'name:atv',
   'name:bxr', 'name:crh', 'name:dsb', 'name:hak', 'name:hsb',
   'name:inh', 'name:kaa', 'name:kbd', 'name:koi', 'name:krc',
   'name:krl', 'name:lbe', 'name:lez', 'name:lrc', 'name:mhr',
   'name:mrj', 'name:myv', 'name:nog', 'name:pam', 'name:pnb',
   'name:sah', 'name:sco', 'name:szl', 'name:tyv', 'name:tzl',
   'name:udm', 'name:vep', 'name:war', 'name:xal', 'name_int',
   'old_name', 'timezone', 'wikidata', 'ISO3166-2', 'ssrf:code',
   'wikipedia', 'cladr:code', 'oktmo:user', 'omkte:code',
   'addr:region', 'population', 'short_name', 'source:url',
   'admin_level', 'alt_name:ca', 'alt_name:de', 'alt_name:en',
   'alt_name:fr', 'alt_name:nl', 'alt_name:ru', 'alt_name:sl',
   'alt_name:vi', 'border_type', 'name:az-cyr', 'old_name:en',
   'old_name:eo', 'old_name:fr', 'old_name:os', 'old_name:vi',
   'addr:country', 'addr:postcode', 'cadaster:code', 'name:be-x-old',
   'gis-lab:status', 'wikipedia:ru', 'wikipedia:uk', 'is_in:country',
   'official_name', 'gost_7.67-2003', 'name:be-tarask',
   'is_in:continent', 'name:zh-min-nan', 'official_name:av',
   'official_name:az', 'official_status', 'old_alt_name:vi',
   'population:date', 'official_name:ca', 'official_name:ce',
   'official_name:de', 'official_name:en', 'official_name:es',
   'official_name:fr', 'official_name:it', 'official_name:ru',
   'official_name:lez', 'official_name:tt', 'official_name:bxr',
   'official_name:udm', 'population:source', 'is_in:country_code',
   'geometry'], dtype=object)
```

And on the visualization of map I don't see any colors variation between regions.

What's a problem with that?

I have tried id column manually via geopandas and save it to geojson but get error: ValueError: key_on `'id'` not found in GeoJSON.

Comment: What are you expecting from this geojson file? Geodata should contain coordinate values that would plot onto your map, but it doesn't seem to have any data besides string names.

Comment: They are contain. The geometry field.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the problem. key_on='id' must be the same as id in geojson.
But problem is that geopandas doesn't display all data. Even with gdf.**geo_interface**['features'] it was displayed wrong id enumerated with 0 instead correct id. NEVER, NEVER use geopandas for analyze your geojson files.

Lost three hours of my time.

Comment: What Tutorials are you following? You mentioned some Tutorial

Comment: for example: https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/quickstart.html

or any tutorial about Folium with geojson

There is no tutorial problem.